# Not able to access image uploaded through HTML forms

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

This is my class that I have created in models.py.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    vegetarian = models.BooleanField(default='True')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',blank=True,null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created_at',)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name


def get_thumbnail(self):
    if self.thumbnail:
        return self.thumbnail.url

    else:
        if self.image:
            self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
            self.save()

            return self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            return 'https://https://via.placeholder.com/240x180.jpg'


def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.convert('RGB')
    img.thumbnail(size)

    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

    thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

    return thumbnail
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from product.models import Product

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category','image','name','description','price']
```

This is my form in html file:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-dark is uppercase">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
```

But when I run server, I am not able to see the image of my product while I am able to see the other details that I want as given in this frontpage.html file:

```
{% for product in products %}
       <li>{{product.name}}</li>
            <li>{{product.price}}$</li>
           <li>{{product.description}}</li>
            <li><figure><img src="{{ product.get_thumbnail }}"></figure></li>

        
{% endfor %}
```

Please explain why so? I want to see images on my frontpage too. When I fill the form to add products, I upload the image and fill other details, but only text details are visible and not image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `multipart/form-data` in your

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```